# Import CSV data into SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I have a table with the following fields:

```
Name (varchar)
Ranking (int)
Age (int)
Favourite Court (varchar)
```

and a CSV file like this

```
name;age;current_ranking;favourite_court
sample1;22;5;Hard
sample2;21;6;Clay
```

I try to import it with MySQL using: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/players.csv' INTO TABLE players FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';` or `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/players.csv' INTO TABLE players FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (name,age,current_ranking,favourite_court);`, with or without file header (that is name;age...).
It does not work, fields are messed up. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name the columns from your table, not the columns as headed in the file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/players.csv' INTO TABLE players
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(Name, Age, Ranking, `Favourite Court`)
```

Also, as noted under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> #### Note
>
> If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` to read the file properly, because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator. Some programs, such as **WordPad**, might use `\r` as a line terminator when writing files. To read such files, use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'`